# Add binary classification columns according for year from existing date column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with dates as such:

```
print(data)
```

```
          date      time  
0   2017-01-10  00:00:00        
1   2017-01-17  00:00:00        
2   2017-01-24  00:00:00        
3   2017-01-31  00:00:00        
4   2017-02-07  00:00:00        
..         ...       ...   
220 2021-04-27  00:00:00   
221 2021-05-03  00:00:00   
222 2021-05-10  00:00:00   
223 2021-05-17  00:00:00   
224 2021-05-25  00:00:00
```

How can I add year columns with binary encoding so that my dataframe looks like so:

```
print(data)
```

```
          date      time    2017    2018    2019    2020     2021      etc.
0   2017-01-10  00:00:00       1       0       0       0        0         0   ...
1   2017-01-17  00:00:00       1       0       0       0        0         0   ...
2   2017-01-24  00:00:00       1       0       0       0        0         0   ...
3   2017-01-31  00:00:00       1       0       0       0        0         0   ...
4   2017-02-07  00:00:00       1       0       0       0        0         0   ...
..         ...       ...     ...     ...     ...     ...      ...       ...   ...
220 2021-04-27  00:00:00       0       0       0       0        1         0   ...
221 2021-05-03  00:00:00       0       0       0       0        1         0   ...
222 2021-05-10  00:00:00       0       0       0       0        1         0   ...
223 2021-05-17  00:00:00       0       0       0       0        1         0   ...
224 2021-05-25  00:00:00       0       0       0       0        1         0   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

via `pd.get_dummies()`:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year']=df['date'].dt.year
df=pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['year'])
```

OR

via `str.get_dummies()`:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df=df.join(df['date'].dt.year.astype(str).str.get_dummies())
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your desired output

Answer (score 1):

Try with `pd.concat` and `pd.get_dummies` like so:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df["date"].dt.year)], axis=1)
          date      time  2017  2018  2019  2020  2021
0   2017-01-15  00:00:00     1     0     0     0     0
1   2017-01-22  00:00:00     1     0     0     0     0
2   2017-01-29  00:00:00     1     0     0     0     0
3   2017-02-05  00:00:00     1     0     0     0     0
4   2017-02-12  00:00:00     1     0     0     0     0
..         ...       ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
223 2021-04-25  00:00:00     0     0     0     0     1
224 2021-05-02  00:00:00     0     0     0     0     1
225 2021-05-09  00:00:00     0     0     0     0     1
226 2021-05-16  00:00:00     0     0     0     0     1
227 2021-05-23  00:00:00     0     0     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can first get the year of date then do `crosstab`

```
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
out = df.join(pd.crosstab(df.index, df.date.dt.year))
```